# How can upper bound be lower than other possible growth rates for function?

Tags: time-complexity

> A description of a function in terms of big O notation only provides
>   an upper bound on the growth rate of the function. – This means that a
>   function that is O(n) is also, technically, O(n2), O(n3), etc

How can O(n) also be O(n^2) etc?

Comment: Is the quote visualized as O(n^2), or does it read as O(n2), without the raised '2'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big O is the upper bound on the running time of the algorithm you use, and if you look at the graph of `n` vs `n^2`, you'll see that (for numbers greater than 1), the line for `n` falls underneath the line for `n^2`. You could say that an algorithm with running time `O(n)` also has the upper bound of `O(n^2)` since the algorithm falls under the line for `n^2`. The algorithm doesn't have to take that long to run, you're just saying it will take less time than that, hence being an upper bound.